# NetBeans Debug session closes after opening Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, netbeans

Ok, when I try to open Chrome DevTools the session between Chrome and NetBeans closes. Is there a way to maintain the session while having a CDT opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Chrome does not "allow" multiple debuggers debugging the same page (tab). One debugger is NetBeans, one is CDT